# How can i read my log4net log during runtime

Tags: c#, log4net

I am creating an application using log4net in order to keep track of all the users that logged in to my system. There is a certain point in which I need to read this log and calculate the sum of logged in users for each of the past few days.
While trying to do so I realized that the file is open as long as my program runs, hence I can not read this file.

Is there a way to dynamically turn of the logger, then read the file, and then unable the logger back?

I Found some relevant answers but they all said to change the config file, hence this is not suitable to my situation

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job. You should persist this information to something other than a log file so it can be readily retrieved instead of parsing a text file. Or you can use something that gathers application telemetry (like, say, app insights).

Comment: why can't you read the file? System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path) should read it, does log4net locks exclusively?

Comment: I ended up separating the needed file from the log4net framework to be able to close the file for writing so i can read the file and process the data

Answer (score 0):

Am I a little bit late ?
Yes you can, you need to allow file write sharing:

```
using( FileStream fsLog = new FileStream( fileAppender.File, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite ) )
using( StreamReader readerLog = new StreamReader( log4NetFilePath ) ) {
    string logContent = readerLog.ReadToEnd();
}
```